# SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: joomla-3.6, smtp

Here is the global configuration of my mail setting. I thought I did everything right but it is throwing "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.". Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. [image]

Comment: Did you manage to fix this probleme? We ran into the same issue on our website. We have contact our provider but they didn't change anything. I think it's something in the PHP-mailer settings. Hopefully you have an answer for us.

Answer (score 1):

If you're 100% sure that everything is OK and that the problem is not because of your host (a firewall setting), then the likely solution is to enable less secure apps. Read [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) for a guide on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the correct Port.  Gmail uses Port 587 for StartTLS, not 465.